# left margin added to listview header without applying any layout parameters

Tags: android, listview

I have a view which is populated by a `ListView` and `HeaderView` , my problem is a left margin is applied to the `HeaderView` from unknown source because I have not applied any layout margin or padding to the layout, neither via `xml` nor programmatically.

so is this a normal `ListView` behavior ?

**Listview layout**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/archos_list_view"
        style="@style/ArchosGridView"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/content_list_vertical_spacing_between_items" />

    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add a simple example xml layout that demonstrates the issue you are seeing, it will help people answer your question more effectively.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I added the layout xml

Comment: There isn't any ListView or HeaderView in your example, please provide one that shows how you're using ListView and HeaderView

Comment: sorry about that, now updated, but the code only uses the header part of the ListView, the footer has been created manually lite this

Comment: it is not my code , it is an open source app that I'm working on. That is why I cannot find the origin of this left margin

Comment: I found the parent of the headerview through breakpoint , so please excuse my bad question , which is now updated nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by doing breakpoint to find the parent of the headerview and found the ListView which was the source of the issue, it was the `style="@style/ArchosGridView"`  that was applied to the `ListView` , so here is the source of the issue

**ArchosGridView**

```
<style name="ArchosGridView">
        <item name="android:id">@id/browser_items</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/content_list_left_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/content_list_right_margin</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>

        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">false</item>
        <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">false</item><!-- true lead to errors on 4.0 -->
        <item name="android:choiceMode">singleChoice</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:textFilterEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    </style>
```

the issue was the **@dimen/content_list_left_margin** of 4 dip was applied (exactly the amount that I expected) but the right one was 0,

```
<dimen name="content_list_left_margin">4dip</dimen>
<dimen name="content_list_right_margin">0dip</dimen>
```

so I changed the `4dip` to `0dip` and problem solved